# Trouble to understand how NIC Profile is written in this XML program

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

I am trying to re-create this C# program [SwitchNetConfig](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=6975) into Visual Basic.NET. All working well except to write IP Configuration (IP, Subnet, Gateway,DNS) for each profile in XML.

As I know it use saveConfig() from ConfigurationHelper.cs to save the profile but I still not get it how the program writing out nic profiles. I am able to create the file and put my profile name in it but I cannot seem to get it to write out the nic profiles.

Where in this code writing nic configuration for each profile? Thanks

```cs
public static void SaveConfig( ArrayList profiles )
{
    // Use XML Serializer to serialize the content of the specified array list
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( ConfigWrapper ) );
    // open the profile file
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( PROFILE_FILE_NAME, false );             
    try
    {
        ConfigWrapper wrapper = new ConfigWrapper();
        wrapper.Profiles = profiles;
        
        // Serialize the array list to the file
        serializer.Serialize( writer.BaseStream, wrapper );
    }
    catch( Exception x )
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( x.Message );
    }
    // close the file
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: My output xml file created exactly the same, but no IP, Subnet, Gateway, DNS, and UseDHCP is written

Comment: You mention that you know that the method `ConfigurationHelper.SaveConfig()` does the writting, but you do not understand how it works. I am gonna edit your question to add that method code into it, because if the link goes down you question would make no sense.

Comment: To understand what that method does you can check the documentation of the classes used, for example [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-6.0) or more [in deep documentation on XML serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization). Do note that the code writes the configuration of the profiles by writting into a StreamWriter (a file) the serialized content (XML formatted) of the `ConfigWrapper` class.

Comment: @Cleptus Alright will do and will get back here for sure, I really clueless how the program get the configuration input (IP, Subnet,..) and write it under NICProfiles node of XML. I think it store in _Profiles arraylist at the main class

Comment: Visual Studio has a nice "Search all references" option if you right click an object, it should help you see where that `SaveConfig` method is called and how they created that `ArrayList`.